# I need help optimizing the usort function

Tags: php

I need help optimizing my usage of the `usort` function because the solution that I came up with is taking much too long. Here is the code I have:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('topicMap.xtm');
$notion = $_GET['notion'];
$associations = $xml->xpath("/topicMap/association[role/topicRef/@href='" . $notion . "']");
usort($associations, function($a, $b) {
    global $xml;
    $a = ($xml->xpath("/topicMap/topic[@id='" . $a->role[0]->topicRef['href'] . "']"))[0]->name;
    $b = ($xml->xpath("/topicMap/topic[@id='" . $b->role[0]->topicRef['href'] . "']"))[0]->name;
    return strcasecmp($a, $b);
    }
);
```

To explain: I load an xml file called "topicMap.xtm" and store it in the variable `$xml`. From this large xml file (more than 1 million lines), I select, using the variable `$notion` which I get via `GET`, certain xml elements of type association and store them in the variable `$associations`.

Now, I want to order these associations according to a name that is to be found, for each of the associations, elsewhere in the xml file (whereby this "elsewhere" is determined by the value of a `@href` attribute contained in each association). Therefore, for each comparison operation between two associations that `usort` performs, the large xml file is searched twice (with the `xpath()` function).

This is taking very long. Here are a couple of performance statistics (number of associations: execution time in seconds):

2: 0.2 seconds

11: 2 seconds

47: 11 seconds

132: 41 seconds

297: 105 seconds

These execution times are not acceptable in my case. Is there a faster way to do what I want to do?

Thank in advance for your help!

**EDIT:**

Combining the suggestions of u_mulder and Sammitch, I developed the following solution:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('topicMap.xtm');
$notion = $_GET['notion'];
$associations = $xml->xpath("/topicMap/association[role/topicRef/@href='" . $notion . "']");
$names = array();
foreach ($associations as $item) {
        $names[(string) $item->role[0]->topicRef['href']] = (string) $xml->xpath("/topicMap/topic[@id='" . $item->role[0]->topicRef['href'] . "']")[0]->name;
    }
usort($associations, function($a, $b) use($names) {
    $a = $names[(string) $a->role[0]->topicRef['href']];
    $b = $names[(string) $b->role[0]->topicRef['href']];
    return strcasecmp($a, $b);
});
```

This solution is much faster than the original one, but when the number of associations exceeds 100, it is still unacceptably slow. Here are the statistics:

2: 0.2 seconds

11: 0.6 seconds

47: 2 seconds

132: 6 seconds

297: 12 seconds

Is there something else that I can do to improve it?

Comment: I advise to iterate over `$associations` and find all related `name`s. Store'em in array. Use this array while sorting instead of quering each time.

Comment: also get rid of that `global` and use `function($a,$b)use($xml){...}` instead.

Comment: Thank you, @u_mulder and @Sammitch! Based on your suggestions, I developed a much faster solution (see the edit of my post). But this solution is still unacceptably slow in certain cases. I am wondering whether it can be improved further. Specifically, I am wondering whether using another XML parser (DOM, for example, or XMLReader) might be faster. But I am not even sure that what I am doing here with SimpleXML can be done with these other parsers since I do not have any experience with them. Do you have any suggestions in this regard?